# Building Blender on Fedora 20, OSL compilation failing due to LLVM/Clang (mismatch) issues

Tags: clang, llvm, blender

Getting the current Blender master from git and running `./blender/build_files/build_environment/install_deps.sh` works fine on my Fedora 20 system until Open Shading Language compilation comes up, failing with the following error:

```
/opt/lib/llvm-3.3/bin/llvm-as: /home/simonrepp/src/blender-deps/OpenShadingLanguage-1.4.0/build/src/liboslexec/llvm_ops.s:112:59: error: invalid use of function-only attribute
define void @osl_sin_dfdf(i8* nocapture %r, i8* nocapture readonly %a) #2 {
```

Investigation led me to [this](https://github.com/imageworks/OpenShadingLanguage/issues/333), suggesting there's a version mismatch between the local `llvm (3.3)` build the installer sets up and the globally installed `clang (3.4)`. So I tried to explicitly tell the installer to go with `llvm 3.4` - `/blender/build_files/build_environment/install_deps.sh --ver-llvm=3.4` - leading me this time, to a different error:

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
LLVM_MCJIT_LIBRARY
    linked by target "oslexec" in directory /home/simonrepp/src/blender-deps/OpenShadingLanguage-1.4.0/src/liboslexec
```

I could not get hold of an explanation for this, neither contrive a working solution myself, so I went for yet another approach, down-grading and version-locking the global `llvm` and `clang` packages to `3.3`, and this time telling the installer explicitly to go with `llvm (3.3)` - `/blender/build_files/build_environment/install_deps.sh --ver-llvm=3.3` - this time resulting in the installer aborting due to not being able to upgrade the version-locked packages to `3.4` ... Argh.

So now I am more or less stuck, and looking for an out-of-the-box solution, or for someone who understands what's up with the `LLVM_MCJIT_LIBRARY` stuff and how that can be dealt with?

Comment: clang must be same or newer than llvm. Personally I haven't had luck building OSL using llvm3.4 yet. Run ccmake (or cmake-gui) in the osl build dir and check that LLVM_CONFIG is set to the llvm-config installed by llvm3.3. Try manually setting LLVM_MCJIT_LIBRARY to the full path to libLLVMMCJIT.a - it should be with the other llvm libs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE: The here described error in the dependency installer script has been fixed meanwhile (https://developer.blender.org/rBf3f991c80fa92ccb7a831b8e8449ff5f21065a9d) :)**

Ok so I tried to remove the globally installed `llvm` and `clang` packages on my system and ran the installer again, leading to a failure due to unavailability of *any* `clang`, which caught my attention, as in the installer console gibberish it says somewhere `LLVM (CLANG included!)`, so where's that CLANG? I found that the .tar.gz the installer was downloading before compilation (`src/blender-deps/CLANG-3.3.tar.gz`) was empty - 0 bytes - and digging into `install_deps.sh` revealed that `LLVM_CLANG_SOURCE="http://llvm.org/releases/$LLVM_VERSION/clang-$LLVM_VERSION.src.tar.gz"`, which translates to http://llvm.org/releases/3.3/clang-3.3.src.tar.gz refers to an incorrect download URL.

The correct URL for the CLANG 3.3 sources is http://llvm.org/releases/3.3/cfe-3.3.src.tar.gz, so I manually downloaded it, renamed it to and replaced `src/blender-deps/CLANG-3.3.tar.gz`, and after another failing run of the installer also went in the tarball and renamed the folder inside from `cfe-3.3.src` to `clang-3.3.src` ... From there on: Success!

Everyone building the sources like this, and without a globally installed, compatible `clang`, should be facing this problem (as the download URL is broken for everyone else as well), I am kind of amazed I didn't find anything else on this. Well well. Case closed.

Comment: Intermediate bad news: Although this allows me to build Blender, I discovered that even completely clean builds segfault right at application startup. Need to investigate if that's connected to this "solution" now ...

Comment: The intermediate bad news were not connected to the original problem described here, but rather to a problem with libyaml (see discussion on this https://developer.blender.org/T38370), which I was able to fix as well.